# How to get content from all nested/linked documents in single query to Prismic?

Tags: javascript, prismic.io

I know that it's possible to pass the config object as the second parameter and defined which fields I need but it's really inconvenient because I have a lot of them:

```
client.query(
    Prismic.Predicates.at('document.type', 'my_page'),
    {'fetchLinks': ['section1.title', 'section1.subtitel', 'section2.title', 'section2.image', .......]}

);
```

Is it possible to get data(content) of all nested fields for linked documents in a single query?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the new GraphQL API: https://prismic.io/docs/rest-api/query-the-api/graphquery 
Slightly tedious but works!